# The English equivalent of ‘As long as one lives one is learning!’

Tags: phrase-request

A saying in my language would literally translate like this: ‘As long as one lives one is learning!’

I would like to know whether there is an equivalent in English for this saying.

Comment: I'd advise visiting sites with proverbs, sayings, quotations, such as goodreads, say:
https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/learning
and 
https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/lifelong-learning
By the way, there's a saying "Век живи - век учись" in Russian, that is, to put it roughly, "Live 100 years, learn 100 years" (the mood is subjunctive and a bit imperative).

Comment: Though not exactly equivalent, your phrase reminds me of *life-long learning*. I found many good quotes here: http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/lifelong-learning. I particularly like this one: “The education of a man is never completed until he dies.”

Comment: "Once you stop learning, you start dying." This is frequently attributed to Albert Einstein but I can't find a creditable source for that.

Comment: We often say "live and learn" when we learn something new. Bob Dylan's "He not busy being born is busy dying" is a poetic version of the same idea, cast in the negative.

Comment: @BobRodes, "live and learn" has a different meaning. While it _does_ mean that you've learned something, you learned it at great cost. In fact, you may have just barely survived the experience that taught you such a lesson (thus the _live_ part of the expression). It's a rueful saying.

Comment: There is an element of ruefulness in the saying, true, but I would say you're overstating the cost of the learning a bit, at least as I use it. For example: "As it turns out, we are required to fill out the form in black ink. Live and learn."  Perhaps I have a bit of a sarcastic streak that you don't.  :)

Comment: Well, in my experience, it's usually been said with a sigh, after learning a lesson at some substantial cost. I don't think that learning something at a fairly trivial cost is an appropriate usage of the phrase.

Comment: Well, ok.  But I disagree with you. :)  A bit of research finds there to be two threads of meaning, the "profit from experience" and "expression of surprise" meanings.  (See Copperkettle's answer as well.)  I find both usages appropriate, and use the term in either.

Comment: @Phil - Watching you and Bob debate this, I think the two of you are on the same side, except for the place where you draw the "great cost" line. You would reserve the expression for when you've "just barely survived;" Bob would use it when he has to fill out a form a second time. I tend to side with Bob, in that, in the many times I've seen this phrased used, the lesson learned was hardly life threatening, and it's usually said with a smile and a shrug. Take a look at how [this gardener](http://cloverandthyme.com/2013/10/03/live-and-learn/) used it in her blog.

Comment: It's a matter of nuance. I've usually heard LaL to indicate a costly lesson, rather than a trivial one. If the blogger lost a whole 20 acre field of bell peppers because she destroyed the wasp eggs, that would be costly enough to earn a LaL, in my opinion and usage. I think that you and Bob are overapplying it, but we're getting into personal styles rather than absolute truths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a saying that seems to be related to the meaning described by you:

[Live and learn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/live_and_learn) (Wiktionary):  An exhortation to gain knowledge from living experiences. Commonly used after an accident or misfortune to indicate a moral lesson.

It is also mentioned as

[You live and learn](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+live+and+learn) (The Free Dictionary): something that you say when you have just discovered something that you did not know.

There's a sample sentence:

> I had no idea they were related. Oh well, *you live and learn*.

P.S. In Russian, we have a saying "Live for a century and learn century through" (Век живи, век учись - Vek zhivi, vek uchis'). Or, "one lives through one's life and learns all through one's life", since the word *век* has an antique sense of 'human lifespan'. It is used to be said exactly in the manner of "live and learn", after one has discovered something previously unknown. Sometimes the contemplative ending ".. and still one dies a fool" is added.

Comment: Note that “live and learn” has a connotation of the lesson being somewhat (but not very) painful, i.e. it’s a statement that you have learned and won’t make the same mistake again. It doesn’t really apply when you weren’t wrong (you just learned a new thing), and it would be a bit trite to use in a serious situation (particularly if your mistake hurt others).

Comment: The saying in question has a similar connotation.

Answer (score 7):

There is a common expression in the US that goes

> You learn something new every day.

The [usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learn%20something%20new%20every%20day&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,learn%20something%20new%20every%20day;,c0) goes back to at least the mid 1800s and has risen in popularity since the later 20th century.

Comment: I also like ["every day's a school day"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22every+day's+a+school+day%22).

Comment: @tobyink As a senior member of my firm, I used to challenge the young staff working with me by posing questions about our rules or how to do something. My line was *There's a test every day.*

Answer (score 5):

[You're never too old to learn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you%27re_never_too_old_to_learn)

Which also has a connotation that you're never too old to start something new.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @PeterBagnall's answer, a related expression in English is:

> Even old dogs can learn new tricks.

Interestingly, there is a related, opposite expression in English:

> You can't teach an old dog new tricks.

This negative expression apparently [dates back to 1534](http://voices.yahoo.com/phrase-origins-cant-teach-old-dog-tricks-7785294.html) - and started as a literal rather than figurative assertion, also one that underscored *difficulty* rather than *impossibility*.

Both expressions have many modern variants, but all with which I am familiar include "old dog(s)" and "new trick(s)".

Using the positive or negative (variants of these) expression(s) reflects a speaker's general optimism or pessimism about learning as people (figuratively) or dogs (literally) age.

Comment: I like this with dogs. We say about horses: ‘You can’t teach an old horse to accept (learn) the collar’, having a similar connotation.

Answer (score 1):

An oft-heard sentiment at commencement ceremonies is:

> Graduation is not an end, but a beginning.

Then there's:

> The more I learn, the less I know.

That ageless paradox goes back a long time. I've found these quotes online, attibuted to Socrates:

> “The only true wisdom is in knowing you know nothing.”
> “The more I learn, the more I learn how little I know.”

Einstein is said to have said:

> “The more I learn, the more I realize how much I don't know.”

while the music group Kansas famously sang:

> “And if I claim to be a wise man, it surely means that I don't know.”

My dad was fond of quoting this Dutch proverb:

> We grow too soon old and too late smart.

These three are not necessarily well-known sayings, but they are related quotes worth mentioning:

> “You'll never know everything about anything, especially something you love.”  (Julia Child)
>
> “I am learning all the time.  The tombstone will be my diploma.” (Eartha Kitt)
>
> “Anyone who stops learning is old, whether at 20 or 80. Anyone who keeps learning stays young.” (Henry Ford)

Comment: Much obliged J.R.! Einstein’s quote is identical in our language. Personally, I like and follow Eartha Kitt’s words.